# Views moved out of place when rotating

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I created a UIViewController (based on [How to switch views when rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267117/how-to-switch-views-when-rotating)) to switch between 2 views when the device rotates. Each view is "specialized" for a particular orientation.

It uses the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification to switch views:

```
-(void) deviceDidRotate: (NSNotification *) aNotification{

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    NSLog(@"Device rotated to %d!", orientation);

    if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) ||
        (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        [self displayView:self.portraitViewController.view];
    }else if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
               (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        [self displayView:self.landscapeViewController.view];
    }

}
```

and sort of works.  The problems shows up when I rotate to Landscape and then back to Portrait. When going back to portrait the subviews aren't displayed in the right place, specially the UIPickerView:

**First Time Portrait**:
[image]

**Rotate to Landscape**:
[image]

**Back to Portrait**:
[image]

If I repeat the rotation process, things just get worse. What am I doing wrong?

The source code is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3978473/forums/Rotator.zip

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the error. It's pretty simple and stupid: I mixed frame and bounds.

In the displayView: code I was setting the frame of the child view to the frame of the parent view, when it should be the bounds of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your offset problems, rewrite the displayView: method as below.

-(void) displayView: (UIView *)aView{
    self.view = aView;
}

Rotations however are strange. you should review that part of code. 
Use the UIViewController rotation methods

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

instead of -(void)deviceDidRotate:

Much simpler, you will avoid that strange bouncing, and you don't need notifications any more.
Do some reading on the apple documentation on the methods i specified above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried changing the displayView: code as you suggested, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.